# CSS W3C compliance for jquery

Tags: css, jquery-ui, w3c-validation

Just recently I studied about HTML W3C compliance and started understanding its benefits. But when it comes to CSS W3C compliance, is it really possible for a web 2.0 website (like: [boxee.tv](http://www.boxee.tv/), [corp.ign.com](http://corp.ign.com/), [guifx.com/store](http://www.guifx.com/store), [guifx.com/_product_61775/Deana#](http://www.guifx.com/_product_61775/Deana#) ) ? I found that jquery ui's CSS did not pass the validation ([link](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.auroh.com%2Ftest%2Findex2.html&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en)) because of css hacks. Are there any other w3c compliant UI libraries which work in all popular browsers?

On a bit different note, can you please tell some good W3C compliant ways to achieve rounded corners?

Thanks,

Akshey

Answer (score 2):

> CSS W3C compliance, is it really possible for a web 2.0 website?

Yes. (Depending on how you define 'Web 2.0', it is a very vague term that is more suited to marketing people than developers.

> On a bit different note, can you please tell some good W3C compliant ways to achieve rounded corners?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=valid+rounded+corners

Comment: By web2.0, I mean sites like these:

http://www.boxee.tv/
http://corp.ign.com/
http://www.guifx.com/store
http://www.guifx.com/_product_61775/Deana#

Comment: That doesn't really narrow it down much … but its really beside the point anyway.